# SLB Instance not created on AlibabaCloud

Tags: load-balancing, alibaba-cloud-ecs

Alibaba Cloud Server Load Balancer (SLB) is a traffic distribution control service that distributes the incoming traffic among multiple Elastic Compute Service (ECS) instances according to the configured forwarding rules.

I am trying to create Server Load Balance Instance with below mentioned code:

```
from aliyunsdkcore.client import AcsClient
from aliyunsdkcore.acs_exception.exceptions import ClientException
from aliyunsdkcore.acs_exception.exceptions import ServerException
from aliyunsdkslb.request.v20140515 import CreateLoadBalancerRequest
# Create the AcsClient instance
client = AcsClient(
   "<your-access-key-id>",
   "<your-access-key-secret>",
   "<your-region-id>"
);
```

But not able to create.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

TO create SLB, you need more code:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/62375.htm

```html
# Create an SLB instance
request = CreateLoadBalancerRequest.CreateLoadBalancerRequest()
request.set_LoadBalancerName('MyLoadBalancer')
request.set_AddressType('internet')
request.set_InternetChargeType('paybytraffic')
response = client.do_action_with_exception(request)
print response
```